# Is it possible to reassign a loop index in a JSTL forEach loop?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Is it possible to reassign a loop index mid-loop, in order to skip iterations?

Toy example, to print a list of numbers `1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10`:

```xml
<ul>
<c:forEach var="counter" begin="${1}" end="${10}">
    <li>${counter}</li>
    <c:if test="${counter eq 5}">
        <c:set var="counter" value="${counter+2}" /> <!-- skip two iterations -->
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

This example doesn't work.  Is there a way to make it work?

I'm not suggesting this is a good idea, I only want to know if it's possible.

Comment: What's your actual usecase? It sounds like you're doing work in the wrong place.

Comment: Not all questions have practical motivations behind them. :]  I just want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Depending on the concrete functional requirement, you need to solve it differently. For example, just only print the iterated item when the condition really matches.

```
<c:forEach var="counter" begin="${1}" end="${10}">
    <c:if test="${counter lt 6 or counter gt 7}">
        <li>${counter}</li>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm well aware of more proper ways to achieve the same outcome.  Could you elaborate on why the `counter` variable is inaccessible?

Comment: Because it's been set/overwritten during every iteration. That's just how `<c:forEach>` works. See also its source code.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't even aware it was open source.  This excursion into JSTL was sort of unexpected.  Thanks for the info!